# Typescript - not implementing abstract method

Tags: typescript, abstract

Why is it complaining with this error? I am implementing activateMultiselect.

> Non-abstract class 'RegionGetter' does not implement inherited
>   abstract member 'activateMultiselect' from class 'AreaGetter'.

Code:

```
abstract class AreaGetter implements iGetAreas {
    _areasList: Array<string>;
    _areas: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
    _selectedArea: KnockoutObservable<string>;



    getAreas(geonameId){
        var self = this;
        self._areasList = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://api.geonames.org/children?geonameId=${geonameId}&username=elion`
        }).then(function(allAreasXML) {
            var allAreasJSON = xml2json(allAreasXML);
            var allAreas = JSON.parse(allAreasJSON);
            if(allAreas.geonames.length) {
                for (var index = 1; index < allAreas.geonames.length - 1; index++) {
                self._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames[index].geoname);
                }
            } else {
                if(allAreas.geonames) {
                    self._areasList.push(allAreas.geonames.geoname);
                }
            }
            self._areas(self._areasList);
        });
    }

    abstract activateMultiselect();
}

class RegionGetter extends AreaGetter {
    _areasList = [];
    _areas = ko.observableArray([]);
    _selectedArea = ko.observable('');



    activateMultiSelect() {
        $("#region-select").multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            buttonContainer: '<div style="height: 64px;" />',
            buttonClass: 'none',
            onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
                alert('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo regarding case sensitivity.

Instead of `activateMultiSelect()` you should write `activateMultiselect()`.